# Passing data through multiple viewcontrollers

Tags: swift

I want to pass data from firstViewController -> secondNavigationcontroller -> secondTabBarController -> secondViewcontroller.

I can pass it to my navigationcontroller like this:

```
if segue.identifier == "StartMatchSegue" {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? SecondNavigationController {
        destination.delegate = self as? UINavigationControllerDelegate
        destination.testString = "lets play"
    }
}
```

but I cant figure out how to pass it all the way.

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjn7g.png)

Comment: Once you starting to want to do this you need to look into a more comprehensive data model for you app rather than just passing things around everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a singleton which can be accessed within each view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in different ways two of them i have mentioned below.

1. NotitificationCenter
2. Closure